# Submitting to a workshop after journal submission

Tags: ethics, paper-submission, workshop

I have recently resubmitted my manuscript after major revisions to a mid-lower tier open access journal.

I am interested in submitting this same manuscript as a proposal to a workshop. On the workshop's website, they say that is acceptable to submit previously published work to the workshop as long as it is from a non-machine learning venue, which I comply with.

On the journal's website, they do not specifically mention workshop papers. They note that any conference papers must be significantly expanded before publication.

I was wondering if it was ethical to submit to the workshop? I feel like this workshop would be a good way to get feedback on how to further develop the manuscript.

Comment: Under which license would the paper be published?

Comment: @Snijderfrey the paper would be published under the Creative Commons CC BY 4.0 license. I would retain the copyright for the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you publish the same manuscript at a workshop, you would be breaking an explicit or implicit agreement with the journal, which expects exclusive rights to the manuscript once they accept it for publication. It seems to me that if you wanted to "develop the manuscript", you should have waited with the submission to a journal.

If you think that the publishing in the workshop is beneficial for the journal, (as I assume you do) then you can ask the journal editor for permission.

There might be ways around this, like rewriting the manuscript and giving it a different slant, but you have probably run out of time for this.

Comment: "which expects exclusive rights to the manuscript once they accept it for publication" This depends on the license agreement. The paper in question would be published open access, and in such a case copyright is often retained by the authors.